# Control the way EditorForModel populate data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I have run into a situation where EditorForModel get into my way by populating submitted data to my model. Let me show you that use case that get me into trouble.

On one side I have a form that can be save into a database:

```
public class Person {
    [HiddenInput(...)]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

On the other side in my controller I have some action that allow me to record user:

```
public class PersonsController {

     public ActionResult User(bool SaveAsNew, Person p)
     {
          if (SaveAsNew)
          {
               myRepository.Add(p);
               myRepository.SaveChange();
               // p.Id is now a new Value.
          }
          else {
               Person updateMe = myRepository.Query()
                        .Where(repoP => repoP.Id = p.Id)
                        .First();
               updateMe.UpdateWith(p)
               myRepository.SaveChange();
          }
           return PartialView(p);
     }
}
```

On the view side I have a call to `@Html.EditorForModel()` and some Javascript that update a  hidden input depending on if you click on "Save" or "Save as New".

But I get in trouble here because `EditorForModel` populate data from the posted data so the Id never get a chance to change when a user click on "Save as New".

So I am wondering if there is some way to clear submitted data. Something like:

```
          if (SaveAsNew)
          {
               myRepository.Add(p);
               myRepository.SaveChange();
               Request.ClearPostData();
               // p.Id is now a new Value.
          }
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several ways to do this.  You could check to see which button was used to submit the form, but this is a little complicated.

In your case, it may work out that you simply add a hidden field to the your form, and then use some javascript to set that field when you click on the add as new button.  Something like this (not tested, but it should be something like this):

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.Hidden("SaveAsNew", "false")

    <input type="submit" value="Save As New" onclick="$('#SaveAsNew').val('true');" />
    <input type="submit" value="Save Normally"/>
}
```